# exception : java.sql.SQLException:illegal connection port value '3306:etude'

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

i have a problem with my code, i'm creating a login using eclipse and mysql ,basicaly i'm trying to connect to the DB , i filled my table with some ligne and when i try to connect with an acount the exception'java.sql.SQLException:illegal connection port value '3306:etude'' i'm not sure where i messed up
ps: i did add a llibrary for mysql but i didn't know how to import it maybe that's the raison

there is the code

login_controller

```
package application;
    
   

 import java.awt.TextField;
    
    
    
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
    
public class login_controller {
        Connection cnn= null;
        PreparedStatement pst =null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        @FXML
        private AnchorPane panel_signup;

        @FXML
        private AnchorPane panel_login;
        
        @FXML
        private PasswordField password;
        
        @FXML
        private TextField username;


        
        
        public void LoginShow()
        {
            panel_login.setVisible(true);
            panel_signup.setVisible(false);
        }
        public void SignupShow()
        {
            panel_login.setVisible(false);
            panel_signup.setVisible(true);
        }
       
        @FXML
        public void login(ActionEvent event)throws Exception
        {
            cnn=sql_connection.connecter();
            try 
            {
                pst=cnn.prepareStatement("select * from etudiant where userName=? and password=?");
                pst.setString(1, username.getText());
                pst.setString(2, password.getText());
                rs= pst.executeQuery();
                if(rs.next()) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "your username and password are correct!");}
                else {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "your username and password are not correct!");}
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
        }
        
        

}
```

sql_connection

```
   package application;
    
import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class sql_connection {
    Connection cnn = null;
    public static Connection connecter()
    {
        try 
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection cnn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306:etude","root","");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "connection à la base de donnée etablished");
            return cnn;
        }
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
        }
        
    }
    

}
```

main

```
package application;

    
import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;



public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("/application/login.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(Main.class, new String[0]);
    }
}
```

login (fxml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: #cbf2ee;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.login_controller">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="112.0" layoutY="42.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#LoginShow" text="LOGIN" />
      <Button layoutX="310.0" layoutY="42.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#SignupShow" text="SUGN UP" />
 
      <AnchorPane fx:id="panel_signup" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="119.0" prefHeight="267.0" prefWidth="580.0" visible="false" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="119.0">
         <children>
            <ChoiceBox layoutX="334.0" layoutY="34.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="188.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="58.0" />
            <TextField layoutX="373.0" layoutY="80.0" />
            <TextField layoutX="334.0" layoutY="121.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="188.0" promptText="email" />
            <TextField layoutX="334.0" layoutY="159.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="188.0" promptText="userName" AnchorPane.topAnchor="80.0" />
         
            <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="32.0" layoutY="30.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@téléchargement.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <Button layoutX="246.0" layoutY="209.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="SUGN UP" />
            <PasswordField layoutX="334.0" layoutY="168.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="187.0" promptText="password" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="panel_login" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="119.0" prefHeight="267.0" prefWidth="580.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="119.0">
         <children>
            <ChoiceBox layoutX="183.0" layoutY="33.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="188.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="209.0" />
           
            <PasswordField fx:id="password" layoutX="142.0" layoutY="141.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="250.0" promptText="password" />
            <Button layoutX="256.0" layoutY="205.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#login" text="LOGIN" />
            <TextField layoutX="142.0" layoutY="83.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="250.0" promptText="username" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection string is wrong. It should be

```
        Connection cnn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/etude","root","");
```

The syntax is jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/databasename

Comment: ohh thaks it works , what a mistake!!! , but i got another exception java.lang.nullpointerException i believe it's in the login_controller but i'm not sure where is the probleme

Comment: Please share the stack trace